# Unable to redirect to third party website(payumoney) with POST data (using webApi controller,angular.js)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, payumoney

I am trying to integrate PayUMoney in my project. As per PayUMoney Docs, I have to redirect my page to PayUMoney website with some Post data. The technologies that I am using are APIController, HTML, AngularJS. Currently I did some reseacrh and found that I have to create a form with some hidden fields and then submit that form. Below is the code that I am using to generate the form fields from server side.

```
public void Post()
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<html><head>");

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("</head><body onload=\"document.{0}.submit()\">", FormName));
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<form name=\"{0}\" method=\"{1}\" action=\"{2}\" >", FormName, Method, Url));
        for (int i = 0; i < Inputs.Keys.Count; i++)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<input name=\"{0}\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{1}\">", Inputs.Keys[i], Inputs[Inputs.Keys[i]]));
        }
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</form>");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</body></html>");                

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: And? What is your problem? What are asking us?

Comment: Thank you #Nikem, am integrating pay u money in my webapi (mvc4) project.My problem is using webapi controller i was unable to redirect to third party (payumoney site),but same code using in plain mvc4 controller am redirecting to third party and successfully to payment. Please help me, what wrong on above code? and how to solve it?